# Retrieve Geocoded KML from Google Fusion Tables

Tags: gis, geocoding, google-fusion-tables

I'm playing around with Google Fusion Tables, particularly how it geocodes location entries.

Is there anyway, using the REST API, to get a hold of the raw Geocoded KML / GeoJSON for each table row?

Thanks!

Comment: Not last I checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the coordinates available through a query you have to geocode them externally and put the coordinates in the fusion table yourself (the coordinates used by the fusion table that it generates through its "geocode" operation aren't available to you in a query).

- related issue in the issue tracker: [Issue 437: Restore support for exporting the geographic coordinates in KML exports](https://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/detail?id=437)